# How do you call a recursion (factorial) properly

Tags: c#, recursion

I have a class with recursion in it to do a factorial. My question is how do I call that properly because I got a bunch of errors when I was trying to do it.

This is my Factorial class

```
public class Factorial
{
    public static double factorial_Recursion(int number)
    {
        if (number == 1)
            return 1;
        else
            return number * factorial_Recursion(number - 1);
    }
}
```

So my question is how can I set the number of times the recursion runs and then display it. (I'm in a windows form by the way) I'm quite new to C# and this is my first time using recursion. Sorry if it's super dumb, thanks for any help!

Comment: factorial_Recursion(10) if you want to calc factorial of 10

Comment: whats the problem? this looks correct?

Comment: I figured it out, I just didn't know how to call it properly. I was thinking it was more complicated than it was thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mentioned you developed this in windows using c#.

Simply call it in a button click event, add a label to your form (give it an id="lblResult") and add a button, double click it to add a click event then set the text of the label to the result of the following function call.

```
lblResult.Text = Factorial.factorial_Recursion(10).ToString();
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thanks.

Comment: @ColeBrowne if this answer solved your problem, please click the green checkmark to mark it as correct.  That way other people will know where to start when they read this in the future, and the overall reputation economy of SO will function as it should :) .  Thanks

Comment: Thanks guys, I know how to. It just makes you wait a certain amount of time before you can mark a correct answer!

Answer (score 0):

> how can I set the number of times the recursion runs and then display
>   it

You already did: you set the recursion to run `n` times given the input is a positive integer `n`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Factorial
{
    public static double factorial_Recursion(int number)
    {
        if (number == 1)
            return 1;
        else
            return number * factorial_Recursion(number - 1);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Factorial.factorial_Recursion(10));
    }
}
```

gives

[image]

or cleaned up a bit

```
 public class MathStuff
 {
     public static double Factorial(int n) => n == 1? 1 : n * Factorial(n - 1);
 }

 class Program
 {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(MathStuff.Factorial(10));
     }
 }
```

also, with what you have, calling with less than 1 will overflow the stack

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a `static` method, then you don't have to instantiate the class and call it as it is.

```
 Factorial.factorial_Recursion(5);
```

See [example](https://ideone.com/loKhVv).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this approach is easy to understand, and it's nice on the eyes as well.

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Fact(4)); 
        }

        static int Fact(int n)
        {
            if (n >= 1)
            {
                return n * Fact(n - 1);

            }
            else
                return 1;
        } 
                         //returns 24
```

Comment: How is your answer really different the previous ones?